# When to use `public static function createInstance()` rather than a usual constructor to instanciate a class?

Tags: php, design-patterns

I'm studying this code:
http://www.w3style.co.uk/a-lightweight-and-flexible-front-controller-for-php-5

In it the author uses a `static` function to instantiate a class.  I'm basically a beginner and I had never seen this.  Why would one use a `static` instantiator rather than the usual constructor?

Here is the code:
index.php

```
<?php
define("PAGE_DIR", dirname(__FILE__) . "/pages");
require_once "FrontController.php";
FrontController::createInstance()->dispatch();
```

FrontController.php

```
<?php
class FrontController {
  public static function createInstance() {
    if (!defined("PAGE_DIR")) {
      exit("Critical error: Cannot proceed without PAGE_DIR.");
    }
    $instance = new self();
    return $instance;
  }
  public function dispatch() {....}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a workaround for PHP, since it is too dumb for stuff like this:

```
(new SomeClass())->doSomething();
```

Oneliners like that are impossible in native PHP. That is why some people wrap the instantiation of the class in a static method to make it possible:

```
SomeClass::create()->doSomething();
```

It helps to keep the scope clean, since you do not need extra variables. It would look like this, otherwise:

```
$instance = new SomeClass();
$instance->doSomething();
unset($instance);
```

**EDIT:** let me quote Gordon here (from the comments):

> Static calls are the same as putting a function into the global
> scope. Calling it will always have a dependency on the global scope.

You should be aware of this fact, as it makes your code less flexible.

Comment: So this was done to implement a singleton pattern - there's no other reason to use such a static creator?

Comment: createInstance() is public, not protected not private so this is not really a Singleton pattern. The method isn't the constructor also.

Comment: @JDelage, @vladv: Sorry, i misinterpreted it. I fixed my answer.

Comment: It should be noted that static calls are the same as putting a function into the global scope. Calling it will always have a dependency on the global scope. It should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

The most common situations are where you want to create a singleton instance, or using a factory pattern.

Comment: The problem is, that this does not create a singleton instance. I made the same mistake in my answer.

Comment: @elusive - This is an answer to the OP's original question of "Why would one use a static instantiator rather than the usual constructor?" The fact that the code shown in the post doesn't implement any sensible design pattern, but uses a dumbass method to reduce two lines of code to one, simply reflects badly on the writer of the original code.

Comment: I totally agree. I just wanted to point out that the OP (obviously) updated his question.

Comment: Thanks Mark - my question was inherently ambiguous. (But I haven't updated it.)

Answer (score 1):

PHP only allows *one* constructor, which means if you want to have more than one way to construct an object, mutliple static function are considered a valid solution. However, just having a static function that calls the constructor doesn't seem to make much sense.

For example, you could have a constructor that takes parameters for each property of the object. And a static function which takes just an id, and does a database call to retrieve all the properties to retrieve the object. This means you don't have to have all the database procedures in your calling code. The static function takes responsibility.

It is often suggested to make a seperate Factory class to do this, but I don't think that always makes sense. You should read in on the subject before making a decision if it makes sense for you.